# Bcrypt pass word changing at runtime?

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I don't understand why I have different values for bcrypt password before inserting and after inserting.

here is my code..

```
        $datas['user_name'] = $data['name'];
        $pass = $data['name'];
        $pass = str_replace(' ', '', $pass);

        $datas['decrypt_pass'] = $pass.'@123';
        //var_dump($datas['decrypt_pass']); 

        $options = ['cost' => 12];
        $datas['password'] = password_hash($datas['decrypt_pass'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
         // here i've different value of $datas['password'] which is matching
        // but as soon as I insert is just after this line, someother brcypt gets inserted
        $this->db->insert('users',$datas);
```

I'm sure my values are getting changed before inserting and after inserting, why is it happening and how do I fix it?

I tried this..

```
$pass1=bin2hex($datas['decrypt_pass']);
echo $datas['password'] = password_hash($pass1, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

$hash = hex2bin('$2y$12$nv7MZpITG2QqTOC91rouBOdn3/WqI6uNUUyP4I6vsEpYh46LD7ZNW');

if (password_verify('bilalmalik@123', $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

Comment: You claim *I'm sure my values are getting changed before inserting* ... but this is likely not the case. Instead focus on how your db is interpreting the data. For example, if your db terminates a string on ordinal 0, you may have a problem. Consider "hex"ing the password hash before storing to db

Comment: What charset and collation is your DB set too?

Comment: utf8_general_ci and "utf-8"  @PaulF

Comment: bin2hex($datas['decrypt_pass']) .. something like this? @GetSet

Comment: That sounds fruitful. Try it out. You will need `hex2bin()` on decoding.

Comment: Please see the edited code, I need to provide hex value in hex2bin, it says @GetSet

Comment: Your `bin2hex()` result would be the hex value.

Comment: That's what I did, isn't it? the  result of bin2Hex is what I've set for password_hash fn,  doesn't seem to work @ GetSet

Comment: oh, it was my mistake on DB side, I was getting password with length as 60, and my DB had only varchar(50) as type, I changed is to 62, now its working, hope it might help somebody.

Comment: As a general rule, assume the language (PHP) isnt the source of the bug.

Comment: of course, nobody is doubting PHP over here.